# Aliasing a layout resource with same name just different screen qualifier

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that is different for portrait and landscape; however on tablets (e.g. really big screen, xlarge layout qualifier) I want to use only the portrait version for both orientations.

/res/layout/abc.xml

/res/layout-land/abc.xml

/res/layout-xlarge/abc.xml

Since the first and last layouts are identical, I was thinking of using an alias. But I can't figure out from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) how to reference a qualifier specific layout in my  statement...

Ideas?

Comment: Why dont you load resources dynamically depending on resolution or aspect ratio or some condition by  setting one default resource.

Comment: I would rather let the platform take care of it automatically ... the less code the better...

Comment: It gets more complicated. I am using these layouts for homescreen widgets, and apparently the merge / include technique doesn't work.

Comment: posted the same question just now before I found yours... :/ no answers here means - there is no answer? *sigh*

Comment: @Zordid's question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7423413/253468

Comment: I got issue with data binding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was fighting with exactly! same problem and finally found a solution, so even if question is quite old, maybe someone find it useful

1. put portrait layout into `/res/layout/abc.xml` (you already have it)
2. put landscape layout into `/res/layout/abc_land.xml`
3. create file `layout.xml` with content

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <item name="abc" type="layout">@layout/abc_land</item>
   </resources>
   ```
4. copy this file into your `/res/values-land/` and `/res/values-xlarge/` directories

Important is, that your `layout.xml` file contain reference to improved (landscape) file `abc_land.xml`, that is stored also in `layout` directory and also files are under `values-x` directories, not `layout-x` once.

Also I tried to put into layout directory two files `abc_land.xml` and `abc_port.xml` and create on them alias from `/res/values-land/`, `/res/values-port/` and also `/res/values-xlarge/` directories, and seems to work, so it's also usable solution to make in layouts some "order"!

Comment: nono, I think correctly `layout.xml`. Check this [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters). There is also description `And add these two files ...` where they use `layout.xml`. I expect that if you'll need to use more aliases, you just put it as a next `<item ...` into these layouts files