# Use portrait fragments in only big landscape?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have 3 activities with fragments A, B, C and have portrait and landscape versions of those fragments.

Now I want to change my layout for big landscape modes, that there are 3 columns with one of those fragments each, so you don't have to navigate  through pages but have an overview over the whole thing.
So that all 3 fragments fit, we need the portrait versions of those fragments. But because we are in landscape, the app loads the landscape versions.
So how can I "force" it to use that version without just copypasting it?
I know that aliasing layouts would be an option, but I thought there are maybe other (better?) possibilities...

setRequestedOrientation doesn't work, because the screen rotates :(
Maybe I missed something there?

Edit:
To clarify...
I still wanna keep the landscape version of the fragments for smaller landscape screens, like phones and smaller tablets.
I only wanna change to that other layout for big! landscape screens

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you do not need the landscaped version anymore, you could just delete it and always use the portrait version. Else, the solution could be create a `content_layout` with the portrait content, and include it on a new portrait layout for use with your 3-fragment activity.

**EDIT:**
I created a project for demo purposes. I have 3 activities, 3 fragment and **3 content layouts** (These content have the EditText, TextView, Button and are included in fragments). You can have then new layouts that also include these content_layout. Instead of copy and paste, you can reuse the content.

Comment: I will clarify that a bit above

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are already using qualifiers for different layout for portrait and landscape. You can be even more specific with the qualifiers and include screen size, like `res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml`. They would not be copys of your current single portrait as you need a container that line up the three in a row, like horizontal oriented `LinearLayout` with `FrameLayouts` which you populate with the frags.

More qualifiers:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml  
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml
```

Even more at:

[developer.android - Supporting Multiple Screens - Using configurations qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with aliasing... obviously I can alias the layout/ and layout/sw820dp/ one, so that there is not much duplicated code, but I wondered if there are other better solutions?

Comment: By aliasing, do you refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891339/aliasing-a-layout-resource-with-same-name-just-different-screen-qualifier ? I have not tried it myself...

Comment: Maybe you've seen this already, but it was new to me: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters

Comment: yep. that is using aliases :)

Comment: Hehe, so why are you looking for _better alternatives_. Seems like this is the best alternative in favor of programmatically do this. Also you would be finished by now. :)

Comment: Just wondered if there is anything better... I have to do that many times in the near future, so why not ask in the beginning? ;)